# What does 'just like that' mean?

Tags: phrase-usage

I was watching a movie the other day, and I saw this expression **just like that** in one of the scenes, the implied meaning was 'for no particular reason'.

The situation was something like this

> Guy 1(says) : I am going to **X** place tomorrow.
>
> Guy 2(asks) : Why?
>
> Guy1 : **Just like that**.

Since it was some foreign movie with subtitles, so I am not sure if these expression are correct are not.

Is my interpretation of **Just like that** correct? or Does it have another meaning?

Comment: I'd say it was a bad translation & that your understanding of 'for no particular reason' is a much better translation, as are "Just to go there" or "Just because" or "Because I want to".

Comment: @Bill: It doesn't *have* to be a "bad translation". OP hasn't given us the movie, so we can't easily check, but it's at least *possible* Guy1 is a fluent native speaker. For example, it could reasonably be a "cut-down" version of *"**I'm** just like that"* (i.e. - I just make spur-of-the-moment decisions like that). Without the *exact* context, we're pretty much in the dark.

Comment: @ Thor: If you can remember the actual movie title, it would probably help. But I should tell you that in my experience, there are an awful lot of really bad English subtitles out there. I wouldn't take too much notice of anything you see in a subtitle that doesn't accord with your own understanding of "valid/expected" forms.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think OP's specific context is a (very slightly) "abnormal" usage, where most native speakers would probably say *"Just because"* (i.e. - *for no particular reason that I can articulate*).

In other contexts, *just like that* is normally used to mean *as quickly as that*, or *with no further deliberation*. In such contexts, *that* references a short (or even, non-existent) antecedent discussion/preparation.

The British stand-up comic [Tommy Cooper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Cooper) used *"just like that"* as a catch-phrase - usually as facetious wordplay ([not like this, [just] like that!](http://www.dailyinfo.co.uk/reviews/theatre/JusLikeThat.htm)), after a bungled "sleight-of-hand" magic trick.

Comment: "Just like that" could also be used to indicate when something is done correctly. "Is this correct?" "Yes, [do it] just like that."

Comment: @imkingdavid: The implication of "correct" in your example arises solely from the context *(**yes**, this is correct)*. Which wouldn't apply in, say, *I explained exactly why the idea wouldn't work. But you still did it just like that, you idiot!*.

Comment: @imkingdavid: I don't know for sure, but quite likely *just* is etymologically related to words like *justice* and *justified* (it's certainly related *semantically* in commonplace collocations like *just and proper*). So your point isn't completely without merit. And there's the colloquial usage *Her Yorkshire puddings always come out **just so***, for example, where it always means *exactly right*.